# combine plots with different variable relations

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

The `df` has three normal variables:`a`,`b`,`c` and one group variable: `d`.

```
df<-data.frame(c(5,1,1,2,3,7,5,4,2,1),c(1:10),c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),c(rep('o',5),rep('m',5)))
colnames(df)<-c('a','b','c','d')
```

Considering these two plots:

1. a-b plot grouped by d:`qplot(a,b,data=df,geom = 'point')+facet_wrap(~d,nrow = 2)`
2. b-c plot grouped by d:`qplot(b,c,data=df,geom = 'point')+facet_wrap(~d,nrow = 2)`

Is it possible to combine these two plots into one plot using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want somethign like the following?

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(qplot(a,b,data=df,geom = 'point')+facet_wrap(~d,nrow = 2),
             qplot(b,c,data=df,geom = 'point')+facet_wrap(~d,nrow = 2),
             ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: YES, that's exactly what I want. Can't thank you more.